# prefs:root URL for Instagram settings in Shortcuts app on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, notifications

I am looking for the URL to open Instagram settings directly from the Shortcuts app on iPhone and iPad.

I can currently open the Whatsapp settings directly using the below URL

```
prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=net.whatsapp.Whatsapp
```

I tried a similar one like the above.

```
prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=net.instagram.Instagram
```

but it doesn't work that way. I searched a lot to find one. But no success. Please help.

Comment: you can't just guess app bundle id(which is goes after `path=`), check out how to get it: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/faq/finding-the-app-bundle-id/

Comment: @Philip you are a life saver! It worked :)

Btw the path I figured out from your answer is as below

`com.burbn.instagram`